# Meterpreter reverse_https website

Tags: web-browser, metasploit, kali-linux, meterpreter

When I make a a meterpreter connection with reverse https how do I change the website that appears when someone types my ip and LURI to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

now I think i understand.

you are trying to change 'It works!' to something else? 
You want to change the content.

You would set HttpUnknownRequestResponse to something different.

If you type these commands when you generate your payload it might work:

```
use payload/meterpreter/reverse_https
show advanced
```

You will see option HttpUnknownRequestResponse. This is set to:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

You can either change this here, or if you are generating an html payload that people browse to, you can edit it in the output html file

I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but where is the output html located?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

If you want to host a web browser on port 80, you can start an apache service that listens and hosts content.

If you are listening on 443 with your meterpreter reverse_https you really can't host content if someone tries to browse to your website on https

let me know if that is not what you were looking for.

Comment: When I start the listener on a local network, it sets up a website with this format: http://192.168.1.109:port/LURI. And I put that on the browser's adress bar it just shows a string saying "It Works!", I was wondering if I can change that

Comment: can you post how you're starting your listener? This will help in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: I start it normally, this is just a feature from the reverse_http/s meterpreter payload